# Understanding spring dispatcher servlet initialization

Tags: spring, servlets

Here is how spring documentation recomends to initialize dispatcherServlet:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

My question is about providing an empty param-value inside the `init-param` tag. Despite defining that param as `context-param` we still provide the empty value. Therefore `contextConfigLocation` should be `null` when passes to servlet's `init()` method. What's wrong, correct me please.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#DispatcherServlet)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Spring Web Applications, there are two types of container, each of which is configured and initialized differently.

- Application Context
- Web Application Context

**Application context** is inialised by config file's that you specified in as context-params and picked up by ContextLoaderListener. This is purely i would consider as business logic related beans.

**Web application context** is child of application context which may or may not be present. Each DispatcherServlet will have associated WebApplicationContext and which takes spring beans from your init-params to create context.

Whatever beans are available in the ApplicationContext can be referred to from each WebApplicationContext.

Reason why we have two different bean configurations is to keep a clear separation between middle-tier services such as business logic components and data access classes  (that are typically defined in the ApplicationContext) and web- related components such as controllers and view resolvers  (that are defined in the WebApplicationContext per Dispatcher Servlet).

Comment: So, actually we have in the definition I provided we have two differnt contexts, the first one is related to the Spring Application, the second one is to Spring Web Application. But when we inject a bean with `@Autowired` what the bean actually be injected if it is defined in both `web-context` and `non-web-context`